# How does a CrawlSpider know what to do with a yielded Request object?

Tags: python, scrapy

In the Scrapy docs, this code is used to illustrate how to pass information to a callback function. My question is, how does the `CrawlSpider` class this code is within know to execute the yielded request object? Is that simply coded behavior? Additionally, is `yield` used instead of `return` to keep the function running and ready to accept more `Response` objects in case multiple urls are being scraped? Would returning a `Request` object work just as well if only 1 url was being scraped? I apologize if these are basic questions, I haven't used Python or Scrapy before.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    request = scrapy.Request('http://www.example.com/index.html',
                             callback=self.parse_page2,
                             cb_kwargs=dict(main_url=response.url))
    request.cb_kwargs['foo'] = 'bar'  # add more arguments for the callback
    yield request

def parse_page2(self, response, main_url, foo):
    yield dict(
        main_url=main_url,
        other_url=response.url,
        foo=foo,
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrapy framework intentionally abstracts a lot of complexity to make coding crawlers seemingly trivial for users. As such there are many features that might seem like "magic".  In your example the `CrawlSpider` knows to execute the yielded request because the method that called the your custom parse method is programmed to expect as much. You may have also noticed that you never actually call any of the parse method(s) directly. They are called by the scrapy internal engine, so when you yield back the results of the parse method, those results are passed back to the caller and processed internally.  Once it is received, it goes through various processes to check if the returned object was an `Item` like object, in which case it passes it off to other middleware and Item pipelines, or another `Request` object, in which case it adds it to the internal `Scheduler` queue of requests that have yet to be processed. It might seem unusual, especially if you are only used to dealing with libraries where you as the developer are responsible of piecing everything together, but it isn't necessarily uncommon in larger frameworks.

The `yield` statement enables a more flexible means of iteration and creates `generator` objects.  Instead of having to evaluate an iterable all at once, it allows you to produce one result at a time and pass it to some other process; afterward it may or may not jump back and move to the next item. In many cases `yield`ing a singular item would do the same thing as returning it.  There are some exceptions though, for example if there is any remaining clean up code that takes place after the yield statement.  For this reason, when working with frameworks and API's like scrapy, I suggest you stick with whatever the documentation recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Yield  - "The yield statement suspends function’s execution and sends a value back to the caller, but retains enough state to enable function to resume where it is left off. When resumed, the function continues execution immediately after the last yield run. This allows its code to produce a series of values over time, rather than computing them at once and sending them back like a list."

So this basically passes the yield to the `CrawlSpider` class as mentioned

Comment: I understand this, but how does the `CrawlSpider` class know what to do with the object it receives? What determines ts behavior when receiving different objects?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking about is the Scrapy Engine you can learn more about the Architecture from here [Architecture overview](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html).

[image: Scrapy Architecture]

About your question, about how the engine can differ from a request object or an item or simply a dictionary, I believe that the engine checks every object that is yielded if it's a Request-Object or Dictionary, .. etc.

how can it do that?

simply by using `isinstance` -> `isinstance(object, type)`

so assuming that a request is being yielded, the engine does the following

```py
if isinstance(Request-object, scrapy.http.Request):
    Do stuff
```

so simply checking the type of the object being yielded the engine can decide which operation to do.